# (PHP & mySQL) Treat rows as columns

Tags: php, mysql, row, entity-attribute-value

I am working on PHP & mySQL based website. I am trying to setup the 'Settings' page in administration panel where I can enter different settings to manage the site. The settings can range upto 100 (or even more) depending upon the requirements. So instead of making 100 columns (and increase if I have to add more columns in future), I want to store the data in row wise format and fetch the values as if I am fetching it from columns.

**REFERENCE:**

I found a similar real life implementation of such feature in the most popular blogging tool 'Wordpress'. For reference, it is the 'wp_options' table that I am talking about.(Please correct me I am wrong)

**EXAMPLE:**

Here's a quick example of what (& why) I am trying to do it that way:

```
--Table settings

P.KEY   option_name      option_value
1       site_name        XYZ site inc.
2       siteurl          http://www.xyz.com
3       slogan           Welcome to my XYZ site
4       admin_email      admin@xyz.com
5       mailserver_url   mail.xyz.com
6       mailserver_port  23
..... etc.
```

As you can see from above, I have listed very few options and they are increasing in number. (Just for the records, my installation of Wordpress has 902 rows in wp_options table and I did not see any duplicate option_name). So I have the feeling that I am well off if I apply the same working principle as Wordpress to accomodate growth of the settings. Also I want to do it so that once I save all the settings in DB, I want to retrieve all the settings and populate the respective fields in the form, for which the entries exist in DB.

**ONE OF MY CODE TRIALS:**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `settings`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (
  `set_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `option_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `option_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`set_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `settings`
--

INSERT INTO `settings` (`set_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`) VALUES
(1, 'site_name', 'XYZ site inc.'),
(2, 'slogan', 'Welcome to my XYZ site');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT option_name, option_value FROM settings");
$defaults = array('option_name', 'option_value');


while( list($n, $v) = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
 $defaults['option_name'] .= $n;
 $defaults['option_value'] .= $v;
}

echo  $defaults['option_name'].'---'.$defaults['option_value'].'<br />';

//The above code gives me the following Output:
//site_nameslogan---XYZ site inc.Welcome to my XYZ site
```

When I run the above query, I also receive 2 PHP Notices that says:

Undefined index:  option_name

Undefined index:  option_value

I would appreciate any replies that could show me the **PHP code** to retrieve the options successfully and eliminate the Undefined index issues as well. Also, like I mentioned earlier, I want to retrieve all the existing settings and populate the respective fields in the form when I visit the settings page next, after storing the data.

Thanks fly out to all in advance.

Comment: The reason that I tend to avoid this design is that "adding settings requires developer intervention", and therefore, it is no problem to add a column to the database at that point.  MySQL can store 65,536 columns per record.  Plus, this lets you store different setting sets if desired.  Lastly, you get to choose the most appropriate datatype for the setting, and a single mysql_fetch_assoc will give you everything.

Comment: The design is called Entity-Attribute-Value or EAV.  Follow the tag I added for lots of other questions from people struggling to make this terrible design work.

Comment: @gahooa: +1 for the useful info. Thanks.
@Bill: Pardon my ignorance, but why would you call it terrible? Just wondering if the Wordpress guys implemented that methodology without knowing why it's terrible. And if they did know about it, why would they still implement it so? I am new to this thing, so more light on this would help my future decisions for a more appropriate design. And yes, thank you for adding the tag.

Comment: @Devner: It's a non-relational design bolted onto a relational database.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect  Or this article about how using an EAV design almost destroyed a company.  http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: Why did Wordpress use the EAV design:  It's very common for those who don't understand relational database concepts to be attracted by EAV, because at first glance it seems like it makes your data extensible very simply.  But you've sacrificed most of the strengths of using an RDBMS, and so you might as well store your data in an XML file.  See also my presentation http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql

Comment: I wouldn't look at wordpress as a pinnacle of good (internal) design... at all...

Comment: @Bill Thanks for the references. The story about Vision, did really give me a great insight, especially the analogy, by the author. This helps me in planning properly for my own design. Thanks again!
@gahooa I guess you are right, considering WP is (almost) following the same principle as Randy. Time to revise the current decisions. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP gives you warning because `$defaults['option_name']` and `$defaults['option_value']` are not being initialized before they are used in `.=` operation.

So just put

```
$defaults['option_name'] = '';
$defaults['option_value'] = '';
```

before the loop and warning will go away.

The rest of the code is completely correct, although you don't have to have `set_id` column at all since every setting will have unique name, that name (`option_name` column) can be used as primary key.

Another thing that you can improve your code, is to use `$defaults` differently, like so

```
$defaults[$n] = $v;
```

Then you can use every setting on its own without looking through two huge strings.

```
$site_url = $defaults['site_url'];
foreach ($defaults as $name => $value) {
   echo $name, ' = ', $value, '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Awesome!!! This takes care of both the issues. I was really after the code: $defaults[$n] = $v; 

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$defaults = array('option_name' => array( ), 'option_value' => array( ) );

while( list($n, $v) = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
 $defaults['option_name'][] = $n;
 $defaults['option_value'][] = $v;
}
```

Then in your view iterate over `$defaults['option_name']` and `$defaults['option_value']`

Comment: +1: Your solution does take care one of the problems that I had i.e. of Undefined index. vava did provide the code which I was really looking for. I wish you had that solution too in your reply. Appreciate your help and thank you.