# MySQL Row to Column

Tags: mysql, row

can any one help me on how can I create a query output using the row data on the source table as a header on my output. Please see below for illustration.

E.G.

Row Data:

```
+-----------+----------+
| colHeader | value    |
+-----------+----------+
| Header1   | value 1  |
+-----------+----------+
| Header2   | value 2  |
+-----------+----------+
| Header3   | value 3  |
+-----------+----------+
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Header1   | header2   | Header3   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Value 1   | value 2   | Value 3   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Is it possible??

Here is my MySQL script. I don't think if is it the right way. Is there any idea on how could i arrive on the above output?

```
SELECT t1.value AS `Header1`,
       t2.value AS `Header2`,
       t3.value AS `Header3`
  FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE colHeader='Header1') t1
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE colHeader='Header2'3) t2
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE colHeader='Header3') t3;
```

Comment: yes, It is possible. Show us your code & tell us where you are going wrong, so that we can help you.

Comment: You could try UNION. See if that could achieve the result you want.

Comment: any idea Fahim? so that I can create it on my own.. :D

Comment: my script is being posted, it works but I don't think if is it the right way. Is there any idea?

Comment: sometime you have added new row this query is not efficiency..see this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997670/php-mysql-treat-rows-as-columns

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this??

```
SELECT  
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colHeader = 'Header 1', value, NULL)) AS 'Header 1', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colHeader = 'Header 2', value, NULL)) AS 'Header 2', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colHeader = 'Header 3', value, NULL)) AS 'Header 3' 
FROM myTable;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc9b5/1)

Note, you will need `GROUP BY` statement when there are more data of ids as shown below in **Demo 2**.

### [Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6be48/1)

Comment: thats a much better approach than the usual self-join